# Why do I not get the new YouTube ui on my tablet?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-10, youtube

I've got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running CyanogenMod 9-20121028-NIGHTLY-p4wifi and I downloaded the latest YouTube app from the Play Store. However, the app still uses the old ui with the 3d carousel, despite reporting a version number of 4.1.23.

I had this same issue when running various versions of AOKP.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest YouTube update has enabled it :-D